# HD gets bad sectors

Tags: hard-drive, hardware-failure

I have a 1TB hitachi that after some use develops bad sectors as reported by HD tune and checkdisk. After reformatting the HD tune and checkdisk report no bad sectors.

I use the disk exclusively for my music collection which is indexed by foobar2000. After some time checkdisk is ran at windows startup and many files are found to be "corrupt"... sometimes bad sectors are reported(But not always). Usually it seems it has to do with the MFT being corrupt to some degree(some files were put in the "found.chk" dir and I've listened to them and they were ok).

I send the drive back and got a new one I believe(serial was different) but the same problem occurs. It only happens on this drive. I have an another one I brought at the same time without having these problems.

I believe the issue is foobar2000 corrupting the file system some how but I do not know this to be fact. I only believe the probability of having the same issue between the old HD and the new one to be pretty low and formatting the drive seems to make it work for a while(but of course I have to restore all the files).

I do not want to return the drive if it is ok and just end up with the same issues(although it would point to foobar being the most likely culprit). I've used a different SATA cable and different port without different results.

Any ideas?

Comment: Read the drives SMART values. If it is failing then that should be reflected in those.

Comment: @Hennes: No, it's fine. Nothing in the warning. What I don't get is why it eventually says there are bad sectors then a format fixes them.

Comment: Weird. I can understand bad sectors. Those are not good but they do happen. And a format can 'fix' them since modern drives detect that that are bad and silently redirect access to spare sectors. But when they do that it shows in the SMART values. If it is not there then I am puzzled as to what is happening.  (well, I could guess to bad cables and ports, but you already checked those).

Comment: @Hennes I do have issues with DMA crc errors on all the drives it seems. The bad drive has a huge number. Either the SATA controller is having problems or the cables are having issues I'd imagine. Not sure why bad sectors pop up but I guess it has to do with those errors and probably why the reformat fixes the bad sectors. (all the drives have 0 bad sector relocation). I can't imagine it being the cables but who knows. I had another drive that failed and f$cked up the main os so I guess the issue is spreading. (Although it has on the other hitachi drive so not sure)

Comment: Any chance to test the drives on another motherboard?  Also, what is the motherboard and the chipset? Some chipsets are known to have problems.

Comment: @Hennes not really. I've been having this issue for some time now with one single hard drive. I RMA'ed it, same problem. (which leads me to believe it is not the HD). Another model HD just now having issues(possibly unrelated). It is an ASrock MB but not sure of the chipset. The problem is intermittent. Sometimes going for months without issue then BAM! corrupt file system, chkdsk reports bad sectors. Format, no bad sectors and things are usually fine for a while. When it happened this time I was attempting to move stuff off then my main OS(the other hiatchi) got it which is a PITA.